# Jquery text align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so the welcome text moves from the left to the center above the image on my website. I need help making the text that I am moving with jQuery align to the center.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box:first').animate({bottom: '', left: '', }, 2400)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text perfectly aligned in the center, your best bet will be animating the transform position rather than the position directly. In other words, the true position of the element will be the center until you transition. This has the added benefit of better browser performance. One step beyond that would be using CSS to animate instead. Consider the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').addClass('active');  
});
```

```css
.box-container {
  text-align: center;  
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.box.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

With the above example, it will animate in exactly the same way without using jQuery, which is ideal for performance.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to move the item half way across the screen using `left:50%`, then to make the text completely in the middle you want to margin by half the width back:

```
$("#test").animate({left:'50%', marginLeft:('-'+$('#test').width()/2)+'px'}, 2400);
```

```js
$("#test").animate({left:'50%', marginLeft:('-'+$('#test').width()/2)+'px'}, 2400);
```

```css
#test{position: relative;}
#box{ width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">hello</span>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$(function(){
    $('.box').animate({
        left: ($(window).innerWidth() / 2) - $('.box').width() + 'px'
    }, 2400);
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```